# скрыть сайт от всех пользователей, кроме поисковых роботов laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cookie, laravel-8

У меня в данный момент нет примера кода, потому что я не понимаю, как можно реализовать данное решение даже на классическом PHP. И хотелось бы поинтересоваться у Вас!

В общем задача такая:

1. Закрыть website от всех юзеров!
2. Вместо вебсайта показывать по всем роутам заглушку (любой html template)
3. Разрешить доступ только поисковым роботам
4. Разрешить доступ по параметрам статическим в URL

Cобственно это и все - но как раз вот это я сделать и не могу(
Подскажите, с чего нужно начать, или в общем схему решения данного вопроса!

Answer (score 0):

Middleware->isRobot

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)

    {
        if ((new Agent)->robot() == 'Yandex' or $request->input('turbo') == 'true') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return response()->view('layouts.zaglushka');
    }
```

Karnel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'robot' => \App\Http\Middleware\isRobot::class,
    ];

'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\isRobot::class,

        ],
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Site', 'middleware' =>'web'], function() {
    // Base websites Urls
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/route2', 'HomeController@route2')->name('route2');

    // Redirects
    Route::get('/route3', 'RedirectController@index');
    Route::get('/download', 'RedirectController@download');

});
```